# Password SSH authentication method in RCurl

Tags: r, rcurl

I'm using the `ftpUpload` function in the `RCurl` package to upload files to an sftp file server.  I'm having difficulty working out the authentication call.

Below is my call:

```
ftpUpload(what = "some-file.png",
      to = "sftp://some-ftp-server.com:22/path/to/some-file.png",
      verbose = TRUE,
      userpwd = "my_userid:my_password")
```

As a result I get:

```
* About to connect() to some-ftp-server.com port 22 (#0)
*   Trying some-ftp-server.com... * connected
* Connected to some-ftp-server.com (some ip address) port 22 (#0)
* SSH authentication methods available: publickey,password
* Using ssh public key file /home/.ssh/id_dsa.pub
* Using ssh private key file /home/.ssh/id_dsa
* SSH public key authentication failed: Unable to open public key file
* Authentication failure
* Closing connection #0
Error in function (type, msg, asError = TRUE)  : Authentication failure
```

I wasn't the one to setup the sftp server, and I'm somewhat of an ssh noob -- apologies.  What I do know is that I'm able to login using `my_userid` and `my_password` with Filezilla and that the server has an `.htaccess` and `.htpasswd` file.

I'm hoping that there is some way to authenticate using `ftpUpload` with just my userid and password.  It seems that `password` is one of the two available methods, but I can't seem to get `ftpUpload` to understand that I'd like to use the later alone.

The `.htpasswd` file seems to contain `my_userid:my_password`, though the password portion is encrypted.  I'm open to loading that in a certain place for `ftpUpload` to access, but I'm not sure how to point `ftpUpload` in the right directions.

Finally, I've tried playing around with and looking through the libcurl options listed here: http://www.omegahat.org/RCurl/philosophy.html and more fully explained here: http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/curl_easy_setopt.html

Alas, no luck.  Any help appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems a little late, but I am currently trying something similar (public key authentication, though) and got it working!
Here is what I did:

I did set up a public key authentication basically following the instructions at http://www.howtoforge.com/set-up-ssh-with-public-key-authentication-debian-etch

That is, I run on the server the command

```
ssh-keygen -t rsa -C "e@mail.com" -f "ir_rsa"
```

to generate a public and a private key. (Just as a sidenote, I first tried to use
puttygen on my local windows machine to create working keys but failed.)

Then I
add the public key to the authorized keys (still on the remote server)

```
mkdir ~/.ssh
chmod 700 ~/.ssh
cat id_rsa.pub >> ~/.ssh/authorized_keys
chmod 600 ~/.ssh/authorized_keys
```

and copy both the public and private key file on the local machine where
R is running. Then I can upload a file from R using

```
require(RCurl)
ftpUpload(what = "myfile.txt",
    to = "sftp://myusername@my.host.com:22/path/to/myfile",
    verbose = TRUE,
    .opts = list(
        ssh.public.keyfile = "path/to/local/pubkeyfile", 
        ssh.private.keyfile = "path/to/local/privatekeyfile"
    ) 
)
```