# how to use password to communicate with sftp by using curl

Tags: authentication, curl, ssh, sftp

this is from question - [question]: [Password SSH authentication method in RCurl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12287699/password-ssh-authentication-method-in-rcurl)

but the problem is, I don't have access to the server, so I cannot use publickey to work with.

and curl says SSH authentication methods available: password,publickey

I assume I should be able to use password as method

and I'm able to use FileZilla and WinScp to talk with server

any help will be appreciated.